# apt-get reinstall requires removal of essential packages

Tags: apt, aptitude

I did a dist-upgrade from debian 8 to debian 9.
Now I need to reinstall xserver-xorg-core.
But in doing so, apt-get wants to remove 'init'.

```
# apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libxfont2
Recommended packages:
  libpam-systemd
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  init libpam-systemd mate-panel mate-polkit mate-power-manager policykit-1 policykit-1-gnome systemd systemd-sysv
  udisks2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libxfont2 xserver-xorg-core
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  init systemd-sysv (due to init)
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 10 to remove and 293 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,449 kB/3,585 kB of archives.
After this operation, 11.7 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?]
```

Obviously, I do not want to remove init.
There is no explanation as to why apt-get needs to remove 'init' to reinstall xserver-xorg-core.
Is there a way to make apt-get more verbose and show why it needs to remove init?
Is it possible to display the underlying logic without having to go to the source code?

```
# apt-get install  init
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
init is already the newest version (1.48).
```

Comment: Run `apt -f install` and post the output.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xegwsGpy